# Powershell parallel or multithreading job

Tags: azure, powershell

i have the following script:

```
   ForEach ($lista in $listas) {                      
  $RG = $lista.rg
  $VM = $lista.vm
  $NIC = $lista.nic                     
  
  Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $VM -Force

  $nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $NIC
  $nic.EnableAcceleratedNetworking = $false
  $nic | Set-AzNetworkInterface

  Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $VM

  }
```

which i can disable on azure vm accellerated network. It works fine but i would like to know if is possible to parallelize it becouse i have to do it on 20-30 vm.

Is possible to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, i havnt tested it but it should hopefully work.

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    param($RG,$VM,$NIC) 
                   
  
  Stop-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $VM -Force

  $nic = Get-AzNetworkInterface -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $NIC
  $nic.EnableAcceleratedNetworking = $false
  $nic | Set-AzNetworkInterface

  Start-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $RG -Name $VM


}

foreach($lista in $listas) {
    # Execute the jobs in parallel
    Start-Job $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $lista.rg, $lista.vm, $lista.nic
  
}

# Wait for all to complete
While (Get-Job -State "Running") { Start-Sleep 5 }

# Display output from all jobs
$res += (Get-Job | Receive-Job)

# Cleanup
Remove-Job *
```